# Why did Barry Goldwater change from opposing to supporting the Export Trade Administration Act of 1979?

Tags: united-states, congress, senate, conservatism

The House modified the bill after it passed the Senate.  Goldwater was among three Senators who voted against the bill.  Can someone confirm that the modifications that the House of Representatives made were necessary for Goldwater to change from opposing to supporting the bill?

[This](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/votes/96-1979/s210) shows he voted "Nay."  [This](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/votes/96-1979/h475) shows he voted "Yea."

I can only guess and assume that the modifications were why, but I have no other information than that.  Sometimes Senators change their position as part of a deal with other Senators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why did Barry Goldwater change from opposing to supporting the Export Trade Administration Act of 1979?

Senator Barry Goldwater (Arizona) voted "Nay". Representative Barry Goldwater, Jr. (California) voted "Yea".

Being two different people, there was not necessarily any change of mind.